# ZED Camera : undefined reference to sl::string::string()

Tags: c++, camera, computer-vision

am trying to compile the hello zed sample using QT and without using cmake, this is my code :

```
#include <sl/Camera.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sl;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Create a ZED camera object
    Camera zed;

    // Open the camera
    ERROR_CODE returned_state = zed.open();
    if (returned_state != ERROR_CODE::SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Error " << returned_state << ", exit program.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Get camera information (ZED serial number)
    auto camera_infos = zed.getCameraInformation();
    printf("Hello! This is my serial number: %d\n", camera_infos.serial_number);

    // Close the camera
    zed.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and i've got too many errors like this :

```
error: undefined reference to `sl::String::~String()'
```

i know the problem is in the linking process but i dont know what exactly i should do

Comment: You need to show how you build your program. That is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(project_name  ${ZED_LIBS})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.